# CODECHEF problem : same output , but one showing wrong submission

Tags: java

BOTH code output will be same for any testcase , still CODE 1 submitted successfully and CODE 2 not , why??

**CODE 1:**

```
int t = in.nextInt();
while((t--)>0){
    int n = in.nextInt();
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(j==0 || j==n-1)
            System.out.print("1");
        else
           System.out.print("0");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
```

**CODE 2:**

```
int t = in.nextInt();
while((t--)>0){
    int n = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println((int)Math.pow(10,n-1)+1);
}
```

Sample test case :

```
2
4
3
```

Output:

```
1001
101
```

problem link : https://www.codechef.com/problems/ZOOZ

PLEASE OPT ME OUT , if you got the logic where i'm wrong.

Comment: `(int)Math.pow(10,n-1)` will produce integer overflow for large values of `n`. For example: `(int)Math.pow(10, 10)` yields `2147483647` because of the conversion from `double` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first solution, you print a string. In the second solution, you print an integer.
When `n` is huge, this integer which is of the order of 10 to the power of `n` will increase exponentially and eventually create a runtime exception due to memory overflow.